# How do I add queried JSON to a page?

Tags: javascript, json

I am querying an API, and I receive the data in a JSON format. How do I add this to my page? I *think* you use the `.append` method, but how do I get part of the data? It's an object, I think, so would I use dot notation? My code is below:

```
$.get("apisource", function(data) {
    $("body").append(data(query.results.channel.title));
}, "json");
```

All help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change this part: `data(query.results.channel.title)` Make it this: `data.query.results.channel.title`. This would fix your problem.